# react navigation 5 badge not rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I follow the official react navigation docs and it say that:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ tabBarBadge: 3 }} />
```

But when add this to my code like that:

```
<Tab.Screen
            name="Games"
            component={Games}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                let iconName;
                let iconColor;
                iconName = focused
                  ? "game-controller"
                  : "game-controller-outline";
                iconColor = focused ? "orange" : "black";

                // You can return any component that you like here!
                return (
                  <Ionicons
                    name={iconName}
                    size={28}
                    color={iconColor}
                    style={{ width: 30 }}
                  />
                );
              },
              tabBarBadge: 3,
            }}
          />
```

Nothing happened what is the problem? How can i fix it?

Docs : [React Nav 5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#add-badges-to-icons)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ur code and it is ok.
Try check:

1. Have u connected ur device to pc properly?
2. Try reinstall the app.
3. Is your tab.screen inside tab.navigator and tab.navigator is inside navigationContainer?

Comment: I tested it on android 9. Which device do you use for testing?

Comment: i tested on android 9 too